# is there any way to prevent a view from being unbound on deactivation?

Tags: aurelia

I find, even when assigning the decorator @singleton(false) to the view-model, that while the view-model does then persist as a singleton across activation/deactivation, the bindings and components, etc do not.

(I assume this is because they are stored in a container that is disposed on deactivation.)

The result is that upon every deactivation/activation of a view with a singleton view-model, the view is un-bound and then re-bound.

Is it possible to cause the bindings to persist across deactivation/activation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one stumped me for a good while.  It also confused me as to why implementing it was not a higher priority for the Aurelia Team.

This takes a fair amount of code to get working.  I have put the code in a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/1e862b9318f4f0a9a8e1176ff4fb727e

All the files are new ones except the last, which is a modification to your `main.ts` file.  Also, all my code is in Typescript.  If you are using Javascript you will have to translate it.

The basic idea behind it is that you cache the view and the view model.  And your replace the router with a caching router.  So when the user navigates back to your page, it checks first to see if there is a view/view model already created and uses that instead of making a new one.

NOTE: This is not "component" level code.  That means I have tested that this works for the scenario that I use it for.

I got my start for making this change here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/173   There is another user (Scapal) made something that works for him and posted it there.  If what I am posting does not work for you, his may help you out.

Comment: I have thought about that.  

First, though I didn't state it, I was looking for a solution built-into Aurelia. 

The code you proposed is, in your words, "a fair amount of code".

You also kindly pointed to an open aurelia-router issue where this issue is discussed and other lengthy coding solutions are given.

But basically you have given me an answer:  

"No, there is no built-in way to do what I want, nor any way that does not involve significant coding.  The Aurelia team might implement it someday, though it doesn't appear to have so far been a high priority for them".

Answer (score 0):

i'm also interested in an answer to this.
maybe i'm now making a complete fool out of me but why not use aurelia-history navigate(..) command?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure how this would help.